# Java generics: Generic parameter defined at method level vs interface level

Tags: java, generics

I'm having the following issue to do with generics. I have the following:

InterfaceA as:

```
public interface InterfaceA {
    public <T extends DTOInterface> Object methodName (T dto) {}
}
```

DTOInterface is just an empty interface.

Then my implementation would be:

```
public class ImplementationA implements InterfaceA {
    public Object methodName(DTOImplementation dto) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

DTOImplementation is just a class implementing DTOInterface.

This is failing because the method in ImplementationA is not recognized as a valid implementation of the method in InterfaceA.

However, if I define the parameter at interface level i.e.

```
public interface InterfaceA **<T extends DTOInterface>** {
    public Object methodName (T dto) {}
}
```

And then define the implementation as:

```
public class ImplementationA implements **InterfaceA<DTOImplementation>** {
    public Object methodName(DTOImplementation dto) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It does work. The method is recognized as a valid implementation.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first declaration says that in order to implement `InterfaceA`, the subclass needs to provide a method `methodName` that works for any type `T` that extends `DTOInterface` *of the method caller's choice*. In other words, `T` is a parameter that the caller of `methodName` gets to choose; the class that implements `InterfaceA` doesn't get to choose it. So when you provide an implementation that attempts to choose a particular value of `T` for `methodName` and only implement that, the compiler rejects your program.

The second declaration, on the other hand, is an interface that allows the implementor to provide a particular value for `T` and only implement its methods for that particular choice. `ImplementationA` choose to implement `InterfaceA` only for one particular subtype of `DTOInterface` (namely, `DTOImplementation`) and provides a method only for that choice of `T`. That's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your `interface` definition has a generic *method*

```
public <T extends DTOInterface> Object methodName (T dto) {}
```

This method states that it takes any type `T` that `extends DTOInterface`. If you want to implement the `interface` you need to provide the *exact same method* in the implementation.

You cannot restrict the method in an implementation because what would happen if you did this:

```
AnotherDTOImplementation adi = new AnotherDTOImplementation();
InterfaceA obj = new ImplementationA();
ojb.methodName(adi);
```

This obviously breaks type safety.

In your second example you have a generic *interface*. This means that when you implement the `interface` you either have to declare the generic type of specify the implementation as a generic `class`.

This means that `ImplementationA` is of type `InterfaceA<DTOImplementation>` which in turn means that you have type safety.